# Сравнение строк, содержащих числа

Tags: javascript, строки, сравнение

Почему при сравнении двух строк "70px" и "622px" первое значение оказывается больше?

Comment: Поскольку на вопросе уже есть метка [tag:javascript], дублировать ее в заголовке не требуется. Так что я его немного переформулировал.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не очень удачно переформулировал. "Сравнение строк с числовыми значениями" воспринимается как `"70px" < 622`, например. Это тоже ложно, но по другой причине.

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно, так стало лучше.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12):

Как сравнить *числа*, содержащиеся в строках, [рассказано в ответе @11111000000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452119/181472). А я расскажу о том, почему такое происходит при сравнении самих строк.

Строки сравниваются с помощью лексикографического порядка. Лексикографически `"70px"` больше, чем `"622px"` (т.к. символ `"7"` идет после символа `"6"`).

> Лексикографический порядок — отношение линейного порядка на множестве слов длины n над некоторым упорядоченным алфавитом `∑`. Своё название лексикографический порядок получил по аналогии с сортировкой по алфавиту в словаре.
>
> Слово `a` предшествует слову `b` (`a<b`), если первые `m` символов слов совпадают, а `m+1` символ слова a меньше (относительно отношения порядка, заданного в `∑`) `m+1` символа слова `b`.

Если первые `m` символов слов совпадают, после чего слово `a` кончается, то оно также считается предшествующим `b` (т.е. отсутствующий символ меньше любого символа).

[Подробнее про лексикографический порядок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA).

То же самое в коде:

```
"abc" == "abc" //true
"123" == "123" //true
"123" < "124" //true
"0999999" < "123" //true
"123" < "3" //true
"12" < "123" //true
"123" < "1234" //true
```

Если вы хотите сравнивать именно числа, а не строки, нужно сначала преобразовывать в целое число, а потом сравнивать.

Answer (score 6):

Символ `'7'` больше символа `'6'`, поэтому первая строка больше второй строки.
Сравнение происходит посимвольно в соответствии с кодами символов.

Answer (score 5):

просто **никогда не сравнивайте строки** иначе, нежели `==` и `!=` . Почему это так работает, знать конечно познавательно, однако на практике:
`parseFloat('70px', 10)` - и только так. Не `parseInt`, ибо в CSS размеры могут быть с дробными долями.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно кому-то это еще будет полезно. Необходимо выделить значимость числа. Из всего списка сравниваемых строк найдите самый большой разряд числа. Например, число 1234 имеет разряд 4, 123 разряд 3. Исходя из разряда сравниваемого числа приведите его к виду разряда самого большого числа. То есть, в строке "622px" число 622 имеет разряд 3 (самый большой), в строке "70рх" число 70 разряд 2. Сравнивая разряды получим 3-2=1 - это количество нулей, которые необходимо поставить перед числом.
Пример:
В данных строках:
"845рх"
"1572рх"
"23рх"
"1рх"
После всех вышеописанных действий получаем:
"0845рх"
"1572рх"
"0023рх"
"0001рх"

Comment: Во-первых, ничего не понятно. Во-вторых, не отвечает на заданный вопрос.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/857047)